# If B is invertible, then $\det (B^{-1} AB) = \det A$

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is if $B$ is invertible then

$$\det (B^{-1} AB) = \det A$$

I believe this statement is correct, yet I'm uncertain how to prove it.
Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Hint: Use multiplicity of det.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: 
$$\det AB = \det A \det B$$

Comment: Hint 2 : $\det(X^{-1}) = \det(X)^{-1}$

Comment: Is this possible?
det(B^-1 AB) = det(A) --->
det(B^-1)*det(A)*det(B)=det(A) -->
det(B^-1)*det(A)*det(B)=det(A) -->
det(B^-1)*det(B)*det(A)=det(A) -->
det(A)=det(A)

Comment: You just missed that $\det (B^{-1}) = \det (B)^{-1}$, but that's correct. And you may start with $\det (B^{-1}AB)$ and get to $\det A$. No need  to start with the equality.

Comment: Just fixed that. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.